# mysql query grouping logic

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

My this query getting 6 records from resale table for shipwynum 151513 : -

```
 select re.recdat,
        re.resaleid,
        IF (re.benownsal != '', owsal.ownshortnam, if ((re.grptypsal != '' &&
         re.bogrpidsal != ''), if (bosal.bogrpshort != '', bosal.bogrpshort,
          bosal.bogrpnam), cou1.nation)) as seller,
        IF (re.benownpur != '', owpur.ownshortnam, if ((re.grptyppur != '' &&
         re.bogrpidpur != ''), if (bopur.bogrpshort != '', bopur.bogrpshort,
          bopur.bogrpnam), cou.nation)) as buyer,
        re.benownpur,
        re.grptyppur,
        re.bogrpidpur,
        re.statuscod,
        re.showinob,
        re.benownsal,
        re.grptypsal,
        re.bogrpidsal
 from resale as re
      left join owner as owpur on owpur.ownwynum = re.benownpur
      left join owner as owsal on owsal.ownwynum = re.benownsal
      left join bogroup as bopur on bopur.bogrpid = re.bogrpidpur
      left join bogroup as bosal on bosal.bogrpid = re.bogrpidsal
      left join country as cou on cou.coucod = re.buynation
      left join country as cou1 on cou1.coucod = re.selnation
 where re.shipwynum = '151513' and
       re.deleted = 'N' 
 order by re.saltyp desc,
          re.recdat
```

Here i have added sample data screen shot got from above query for shipwynum 15153:-

[image]
When i add limit clause `LIMIT 1` then its getting the first one record which i expected. But its only for one ship that have shipwynum = 151513. I want to get first one record for every ship.

What changes i do for get such a records for every ship.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: use group by and remove limit clause. use `group by re.shipwynum` at the end of query and you will get one record for all ship.

Comment: not only for one record, i want to get first record for every resale transaction. I above query if i found any other record discarding first one then it would be the wrong. The order are comming from order by clause.

Comment: Can you add some sample data? From the look of the query, you should be getting one row for each resale transaction.

Comment: that's why I told you to remove the limit clause and use group by and you will get which you want. try it dear.

Comment: When i removed limit and added `group by re.shipwynum` only for above one ship(shipwynum = 151513) then its getting the 3rd record not first ?

Comment: so your question / request would be for each shipwymun get [n] records right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your query as an internal query and group it outside. Try your query as :

```
select abc.recdat, abc.resaleid, abc.seller, abc.buyer,abc.benownpur,
abc.grptyppur, abc.bogrpidpur, abc.statuscod, abc.showinob, abc.benownsal, abc.grptypsal, abc.bogrpidsal

  from ( select re.recdat,
        re.resaleid,
        IF (re.benownsal != '', owsal.ownshortnam, if ((re.grptypsal != '' &&
         re.bogrpidsal != ''), if (bosal.bogrpshort != '', bosal.bogrpshort,
          bosal.bogrpnam), cou1.nation)) as seller,
        IF (re.benownpur != '', owpur.ownshortnam, if ((re.grptyppur != '' &&
         re.bogrpidpur != ''), if (bopur.bogrpshort != '', bopur.bogrpshort,
          bopur.bogrpnam), cou.nation)) as buyer,
        re.benownpur,
        re.grptyppur,
        re.bogrpidpur,
        re.statuscod,
        re.showinob,
        re.benownsal,
        re.grptypsal,
        re.bogrpidsal,
        re.shipwynum
 from resale as re
      left join owner as owpur on owpur.ownwynum = re.benownpur
      left join owner as owsal on owsal.ownwynum = re.benownsal
      left join bogroup as bopur on bopur.bogrpid = re.bogrpidpur
      left join bogroup as bosal on bosal.bogrpid = re.bogrpidsal
      left join country as cou on cou.coucod = re.buynation
      left join country as cou1 on cou1.coucod = re.selnation
 where re.shipwynum = '151513' and
       re.deleted = 'N' 
 order by re.saltyp desc,
          re.recdat)abc group by abc.shipwynum
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use this query - the purpose is to get [n] resaleids for each shipwynum, where [n=2] is

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(resaleid, CHAR(8)) ORDER BY resaleid DESC), ',', 2)) AS ID FROM resale WHERE deleted = 'N' GROUP BY shipwynum
```

Please not that GROUP_CONCAT result is truncated to max len 1024 (group_concat_max_len).
And this might have performance issue so please feel free to update and optimize as needed.

Other suggestion would be to set a rank but not how will work this for you. You can check rank : http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php#rank

Hope this helps.

```
SELECT  re.recdat,
        re.resaleid,
        IF (re.benownsal != '', owsal.ownshortnam, if ((re.grptypsal != '' && re.bogrpidsal != ''), if (bosal.bogrpshort != '', bosal.bogrpshort, bosal.bogrpnam), cou1.nation)) as seller,
        IF (re.benownpur != '', owpur.ownshortnam, if ((re.grptyppur != '' && re.bogrpidpur != ''), if (bopur.bogrpshort != '', bopur.bogrpshort, bopur.bogrpnam), cou.nation)) as buyer,
        re.benownpur,
        re.grptyppur,
        re.bogrpidpur,
        re.statuscod,
        re.showinob,
        re.benownsal,
        re.grptypsal,
        re.bogrpidsal

FROM resale AS re
      left join owner as owpur on owpur.ownwynum = re.benownpur
      left join owner as owsal on owsal.ownwynum = re.benownsal
      left join bogroup as bopur on bopur.bogrpid = re.bogrpidpur
      left join bogroup as bosal on bosal.bogrpid = re.bogrpidsal
      left join country as cou on cou.coucod = re.buynation
      left join country as cou1 on cou1.coucod = re.selnation 

WHERE LOCATE (re.resaleid, 
(
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(it.resaleid) AS ids
        FROM (
                SELECT (SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(CONVERT(resaleid, CHAR(8)) ORDER BY resaleid DESC), ',', 2)) AS ID FROM resale WHERE deleted = 'N' GROUP BY shipwynum
            ) it
)) <> 0 
    /* AND re.deleted = 'N' */
 order by re.saltyp desc,
          re.recdat
```